# How to change read-more color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm working on a reactjs portfolio with sass and i installed [read-more package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-more-react) using `npm i read-more-react` and i found out that i can't find a way to change the color of the text "Read more", can you help me to find a way around to fix my problem?

This is my code:

```
<div>
  <p className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
    <ReadMoreReact
       text={work.description}
       min={30}
       ideal={100}
       max={150}
       readMoreText="Read more"
     />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read more` button has a class called `read-more-button`, just style this class.

For example.

```
.read-more-button {
    color: red;
}
```